# Rails query a model defined method in the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to define `LineItems` in a controller based on some of it's Table column attributes and Model defined methods, but I don't know how to write that.

My LineItem table includes a `opt_in` boolean. That's easy to query:

```
Controller:
def index
   @line_items = LineItems.where(opt_in: true)
end
```

But I also have a method in the `line_item` model that goes like:

```
Model:
def cert_approved?
   if product.is_cert_approved?
     true
   else
     false
   end
end
```

So I need to query LineItems that have been opted in AND that have been admin_approved.

Something like:

```
@line_items = LineItems.where(opt_in: true).where(cert_approved? true)
```

(but obviously not that, as that doesn't work)

How would I go about doing this?

Product relation to Line Item in `product` model:

`has_many :line_items, through: :variants_including_master`

In the `line_item` model:

`scope :cert_approved, -> { includes(:product).where spree_products: {is_cert_approved: true} }`

Comment: can you show your model LineItems and User table relationships

Comment: wow...I didn't even post the question correctly...I put in the wrong method.  It actually checks the line_item.product in the method (corrected above).  I'll post relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already defined the `scope :cert_approved` and its logic is the same as method `cert_approved?`, you can use this query.

```
@line_items = LineItems.cert_approved.where(opt_in: true)
```

If you still want to use the `cert_approved?` method, you will have to pass it via select block like this (Slow performance than using scope)

```
@line_items = LineItems.where(opt_in: true).select { |l| l.cert_approved? }
```

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the first answer.
Instead of using `select` you can also write an SQL query, joining the necessary tables and then querying the `cert_approve` like you do it in the scope.
Another hint, you can write the `cert_approved?` more elegantly like so:

```
def cert_approved?
  product.is_cert_approved?
end
```

Since `product.is_cert_approved?` will return a boolean you don't have to specify that.